# How to have a hidden form field appear with a form action of mailto?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to make a form for a web design class. The form action HAS to be a mailto. The form also needs a hidden field that pops up after I hit the submit button. Everything looks nice so far, but after I upload my file to the school server, nothing happens after I click the submit button. I'm not to sure what's causing the problem. Here's my code:

```
<form action="mailto:email@example.com" method="GET" enctype="text/plain"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Vote Your Favorite Month(s)!</strong></legend> <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="votemonth" value="Jan"> January | 
        <input type="checkbox" name="votemonth" value="Feb"> February | 
        <input type="checkbox" name="votemonth" value="Mar"> March <br/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="success-link" value="thankyou.html">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Restart"></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have the thankyou.html file in the same location of this file. I've tried changing up email addresses, using POST, taking out the enctype, changing the location of the hidden input type, but none of that changed anything.

Comment: Don't use a hidden type.  Use a normal element, hide it,  then show it using CSS.

Comment: @SteveWellens — Hidden inputs are normal elements. Why would using a different kind of element and hiding it with CSS help?

Comment: @Quentin - Because it would work?

Comment: @SteveWellens — It has no more chance of working than a hidden input.

Comment: @Quentin You can toggle the visibility of a 'normal' element but not hidden elements.  
    `<input type="text" value="Input Visible" />  
     <input type="text" value="Input Not Visible" style="display:none" />  
     <input type="hidden" value="Hidden 'visible'" style="display:normal" />  
     <input type="hidden" value="Hidden Not Visible" />`  

You sure have a lot of reputation points.   I'm betting I am missing something :)

Comment: @SteveWellens — The question isn't very specific, but I'm pretty sure that "appear" in this context means either "in the submitted form data" or "the browser visits the URL specified in the field" and not "the input itself is displayed for the user to edit".

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields work just like any other field.

The basic problem is that [mailto: as a form action does not work](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) well enough to use on the WWW. It only works if the visitor has an unlikely combination of compatible browser and default email client.

If you have that combination of software, then the data in the field will be included in the generated email.

Submitting a mailto: form will not cause the browser to load a new HTML document.